# printing the scroll height during a jQuery scrollTop animation

Tags: jquery, animation, scrolltop

Can jQuery animate send the scrollheight as it animates or should I create a separate function, and if the latter, how would that function go?

http://jsfiddle.net/A2s9Q/

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: thanks @micha , I've used scrollTo before and it's great, I just didn't need the whole package for this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scroll handler to update the label.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $("#scrollHeight").html($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A2s9Q/7/

Comment: could you explain why you chose to encapsulate both the init scrolling function and the new function within a $(function)? also, thank you, your solution works really well

Comment: The jQuery ready() or equivalent $() simply waits until the document loads to bind any handlers to ensure the timing of your scripts occur at just the right moment.  Technically, the on() handler doesn't need to be called when the document is ready because of how it operates so that may have been overkill.  Read more about ready() here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and on() here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
(function updateScrollheight(){
    if(animating){
        $('#scrollHeight').html($(document).scrollTop());
        setTimeout( updateScrollheight, 200 );
    }
})();
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WLTFu/1/)**:

Answer (score 1):

you could use the step option from .animate( properties, options ) where tihs goes into the options array along with your other options

```
step: function( now, fx ){$('#scrollHeight').html(now)}
```